# Dynamic type not honoring font color set in storyboard

Tags: ios, fonts

I am setting a cell with detail and have the title font set to Headline and the detail font to Footnote.
I've changed the detail font color in storyboard, however when changing the font size under settings -> accessibility the detail; font turns back to black.
Do I need to set the font programmatically also?

Comment: No. If u set the text color in storyboard. there is no need to change programmatically

Comment: I have a orange set in storyboard for the detail font in my tableview. When the user changes the font size in the IOS settings, the tableview font changes colour to default black. How do I keep the font I set in storyboard if not via program? Is there some setting in storyboard to set other than the colour?

Comment: This is surely a bug, which is still not resolved btw. Please file a bug report. To workaround, you can manually set the color in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Did you get this answered? Is this a bug or something the app must change every time the dynamic type changes?

Comment: I've reported the bug, not resolved yet.